# Read basic object properties from PPTX or ODF

Tags: javascript, php, powerpoint, odf

I need to read a few "basic" information from PPTX or ODF slides, such as objects' position, size, font, color, media source in the case of pictures and videos.

I have been looking around for libraries (PHP / Javascript) or even just for format documentation so to write something from the ground up, but couldn't find anything suitable.

Any good recommendation?

Comment: Have you looked at [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation) from PHPOffice? I haven't used it myself but I use their spreasheet library which works like a charm.

Comment: Writes to presentations, doesn't read

Comment: What do you mean? There is a [reader interface](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/blob/develop/src/PhpPresentation/Reader/ReaderInterface.php) implemented for several presentation types that allows you to retrieve a `PHPPresentation` object. From there you can read properties, get slides count and access individual slides.

Comment: sorry, project intro only mentions "writing" and I also got this project mixed up with something I else I tried previously, also write-only. Going to test it, thanks